# Word automation dynamic bookmarks

Tags: c#, word-automation

I have this problem where I have a number of tables, **Undefined number of tables**
and I'm constructing a word document using c#, I need to add each table right after the previous one ended, 
I tried dynamically adding a bookmark at the end of the loop and then add the needed table but the format was not correct, the things overlapped and things at the beginning of page became last, I'm lost here can you help me??

I did this before by adding a table in the document and then insert a new table in each row of parent table, but this make some properties not apply to the child table

Comment: How can we help you without any code to check?

Comment: Did you try to run the code step by step in the debugger? It would help you to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Try using content controls and here is an excellent article on MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197932(office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Many applications use Word automation that needs the clients to have MS Office installed but there are some companies that are likely run by MS employees/coders who understand well about window's word documents [its internal structures] and thus they do not rely on MS OFFICE but still are able to create applications like yours, their applications should be of better worth. Give it up!

Answer (score 0):

for that particular problem I used new paragraph for each table I wanted to insert